# Elastic Load Balancing using a chain of domains/hosts

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, cname-record, amazon-elb

I've setup an elastic load balancer on EC2 which (for example) has the public DNS (A Record) of:

**LB-165746761.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com**

I've then registered a domain which I want to act as my public domain for the load balancer by configuring a CNAME record which points to the public DNS of the load balancer:

**CNAME loadbalancer.domain.com -> LB-165746761.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com**

I then have a public website domain which I have setup a CNAME for to point to the host name of the loadbalancer:

**CNAME www.mysite.com -> loadbalancer.domain.com**

The example [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/index.html?using-domain-names-with-elb.html) has the public site being setup with a CNAME directly to the  load balancer.

The reason for this chain is that we want to give our clients a single friendly DNS rather than the ELB generated one to set their domains up to point to (of which there are hundreds). We figure this wil also give us a single place to update should the public DNS of the ELB change (the CNAME record for loadbalancer.domain.com).

My question is whether it's firstly possible to chain CNAME records together like this, whether it's recommended and whether there are any down sides to doing this in the EC2 ELB environment?

Comment: I am planning to have the same set up soon. How did this go for you? How bad is the latency? Is it noticeable compared to connecting through the ELB URL?

Comment: I'm also very interested in an follow-up experience-- how is the latency?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's possible to chain CNAME records but it's not always recommended.
To prevent loops, servers usually have a limit on the number of times they'll restart a query. And since it's not common to have long chains of CNAMEs, the limit is typically pretty low, like 5-10, and most of this can be taken up by having to resolve NS records in delegations.

Your set-up is pretty much identical to the set-up we have here and it works fine.

Comment: +1 No idea if its the best solution, but it's also what we use and it works just fine. I'd be tempted to remove the middle record and just have 'CNAME www.mysite.com -> LB-165746761.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com' if it doesn't cause too much pain

Comment: @psatk - thanks. Out of interest did you use any tools or services to help diagnose issues with the DNS - I can't actually tell if my public website domain is reaching the load balancer at all, I just get a browser level "could not find www.mysite.com" error.

Comment: Didn't really have any issues with setting it up worked first time, you could run a trace route. To make it harder EC2s don't respond to ping requests, given this is now best part of month old I hope you have it sorted now.

Comment: @psatek: You mentioned that this is the set up you are currently using. How bad is the latency? Is it really noticeable? I plan to have a similar set up soon.

Comment: It didn't add any noticeable latency.

Comment: @stephanian Yep all sorted now, chaining them seems fine and there is no _noticeable_ latency. Thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

You *can* chain CNAME records... but remember that you'll end up with extra latency as your clients will have to do multiple lookups to find the end result.

Comment: How bad would the extra latency be? Do you have any information or references testing this? Thanks.

Comment: It largely depends on all the DNS servers involved... and connectivity from each client.  There is no 100% way to test this as everyone in the world is connected via different internet providers across the globe.

Comment: I understand. I was just thinking, maybe in a specific case, with everything else equal, the net effect can be measured. But I see why that would be highly variable. Thanks.